# What is the harm of using html custom elements which was created in the page itself?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Is there any harm if  custom tags are used and created based on one's choice?
like the one below

```
<hello>hi there!</hello>
```

I tried using CSS

```
hello{
    color:red;font-family:arial;
}
```

The above code works

I have used the above and also can add CSS. is there any harm of doing this, or the CSS features these won't support?

This is purely out of curiosity so don't suggest CSS edits or solutions please.

Comment: That won't work across all browsers (out of the box), Chrome or whatever you are using is just being kind to you. Don't deploy that code to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why you can't make up elements

**It is not valid HTML.** Therefore how it behaves will be unpredictable.

It may work in some browsers, currently, but if any of your users visit your site on a different browser, they may get a totally different experience. Further to that, support could be dropped, or change at any time without warning.

### Other options for custom elements

It is actually possible to [define your own Document Type Definition (DTD)](http://jkorpela.fi/html/own-dtd.html), however that too is [not a good idea](https://www.w3.org/Style/customdtd.en.html).

Your best bet is to either stick with normal, well-supported HTML elements ([see here for list of valid elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)), or to use a web component framework, such as [Vue](https://vuejs.org/), [Angular](https://angular.io/) or [React](https://reactjs.org/), for custom elements/ components.

Don't forget, that you can add the `class` attribute (as well as others) to any element for styling, so for your use-case, there isn't any need to have additional elements.

Comment: [Custom Elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements) are a standard, no DTD needed, but there is plenty of other code that needs to be implemented to use that standard. You don't have to use a framework to build them however.

Comment: @HereticMonkey This won't work on IE, only partially on Safari and Mobile. From my experience, the way browsers deal with custom elements keeps changing, so I now stay well away from them.

Comment: Well, nothing new works in IE :-). [It works in a pretty decent cross-section of browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elementsv1), but certainly some hesitance is warranted.